# How to restrict a route to an admin user in Meteor?

Tags: meteor

as an iOS developer primarily, I'm very new to webdev.  I'm looking into Meteor and have some questions regarding routing -- my apologies if they are very easy.

I am using the Meteor Router package to create routes, but I would like to have some pages only accessible to the admin user.

```
  Meteor.Router.add({
        '/'         : 'home',
        '/admin'    : 'admin'
    });
```

So I have a simple route setup as above, but I'm not sure how to restrict access to the /admin route.

Is it as simple as something like this?  What would be a good way to restrict the route to the /admin page and show a warning or perhaps even redirect them back to the / page?

Thank you!

**client.html**

```
<head>
   <title>My App</title>
</head>

<body>
   {{renderPage}}
</body>

<template name="home">
    {{greeting}}
</template>

<template name="admin">
    {{greeting}}
</template>
```

**client.js**

```
Template.admin.greeting = function () {
   var currentUser = Meteor.user();
   if (null !== currentUser && 'admin' === currentUser.username) {
       return "Hello Admin!";
   }
   else{
      return "Sorry, only admins can see this page";
   }
};
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The best way to restrict access to a route is with the router itself (rather than pushing the problem to your controller). You have a couple of choices in how you do this:

#### Routing Function

You could make the `/admin` route look like:

```
'/admin': function() {
  return {
    as: 'admin',
    to: function() {
      if (Meteor.user() && Meteor.user().username === 'admin') {
        return 'admin';
      } else {
        return 'unauthorized';
      }
    }
  };
}
```

I'm assuming you have an `unauthorized` template that renders a `403` page or something informative.

#### Filter

Alternatively, you can leave your original `/admin` route as it was and add a filter:

```
Meteor.Router.filters({
  'needsAdmin': function(page) {
    if (Meteor.user() && Meteor.user().username === 'admin') {
      return page;
    } else {
      return 'unauthorized';
    }
  }
});
```

and use it like so:

```
Meteor.Router.filter('needsAdmin', {only: 'admin'});
```

Personally, I like the filter option because it's reusable and it's a little more obvious what's going on.

Comment: Thank you for introducing the filters method.  In your code above, would it be possible to redirect the user to a 403 page in the `else` portion, rather than `return 'unauthorized'` ?

Comment: @thinklinux Not really. Technically there is no way to prevent a user from doing anything on the client (since he can alter the code running in his browser). The best you can do is to add client-side checks like above **AND** publish only the data the user should be allowed to see (controlled on the server) **AND** secure your database mutations (allow/deny/etc.). In the worst case, a user could *get to* an admin page but not be able to see or do anything.

Comment: @DavidWeldon I totally agree with you. But I don't want random users to be able to see the admin page because although they can't insert, update, remove anything they can see sensitive data. You can restrict the published data by user but can you restrict it by url too? For example if the user is on the home page he will receive some data but if he is on the admin page the server will not publish that data to him? And don't you think that one 307 redirect if the user is not admin is more easier to do?

Comment: @thinklinux It depends on how you set up your publications. For example, let's say in your admin route (assuming iron-router) you get your admin data with: `Meteor.subscribe('documentsForAdmin')`. The server-side publish function could then validate the user is an admin before sending the documents. Furthermore, your router could validate the user is indeed an admin before showing the page. We can trust the server to only publish the authorized data, however we cannot trust the router because the client could have patched his code to allow this.

Comment: @DavidWeldon Thanks! I didn't think of that. I can make two publish functions - one for the client and one for the admin users with different data where I want to. There is my problem : )

Comment: @DavidWeldon thank you so much for this reply of yours, i got a meteor app complete myself and about to deploy it, and was shocked to see there is apparently no way to initially restrict access to only testers. I guess we also can't restrict access to Meteor apps by IP, correct? Also, does your solution you wrote above apply for iron-router too? Or only for Meteor router package?

Answer (score 2):

Another solution is to use [Roles](https://atmosphere.meteor.com/package/roles) package and make sure the user has the 'admin' role before serving data.

```
$ mrt add roles
```

Then you can check for roles like with a nice syntax:

```
if(!Roles.userIsInRole(Meteor.user(), ['admin'])) {
    // Redirect...
}
```

Roles is integrated with the Meteor accounts system and plays nicely with most of the accounts packages.

If you are looking to manage accounts (create/delete Roles and add/remove Roles from a given user) I've created the package [Accounts Admin UI](https://github.com/hharnisc/meteor-accounts-admin-ui-bootstrap-3). The README has a quickstart and some some notes on how to integrate this with other routing packages.

```
$ mrt add accounts-admin-ui-bootstrap-3
```

Comment: Nice, that's the way to do it!

Comment: I just wrote some kind of summary for this package. I think it should help: http://journal.gentlenode.com/meteor-13-managing-user-roles/

Comment: accounts-admin-ui-bootstrap-3 is a wrapper that does all of that for you

Answer (score 1):

Use the `and` parameter:

```
Meteor.Router.add({
  '/admin': { to: 'admin', and: function() {
    if (!Meteor.user() || Meteor.user().name != 'admin'){
      Meteor.Router.to('/');
    }
  }}
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Everyone here has made great points on how to protect an admin panel on the router level. Another possibility is to skip the router all together. I've recently done this with [Meteor Candy](https://www.meteorcandy.com), a drop-in admin package for Meteor.

The idea is, you could create a Reactive-Dict to hold the state of the admin interface. If you place it into a package, you can ensure that it never collides with your application code. And with the new Dynamic Imports feature, you can virtually keep it off the client until its needed.

Here's how that might work:

```
<template name="adminPanel">
    {{#if show}}
        {{> adminPanelUI}}
    {{/if}}
</template>

AdminUI = new ReactiveDict();

Meteor.defer(function () {
    Blaze.render(Template.MeteorCandy, document.body);
});

Template.adminPanel.helpers({
    show: function () {
        if (AdminUI.get('show')) {
            return true;
        }
    }
})
```

On top of that, all you would need is to define the occasion that sets "show" to a truth-y value.